# IIS 8.5 Threads per processor limit

Tags: iis, application-pool, iis-8.5

In IIS 7, you can specify the number "Threads Per Processor Limit". I am trying to do the same thing on IIS 8.5.

Is it the "maximum Concurrent connections" as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/limits) in IIS 8.5

[image]

There is also this:

[image]

What is the difference between the **Maximum Concurrent Connection**  and **maximumConcurrentThreadsPerCPU**?

Answer (score 0):

Hussein, the "threads per processor" feature is still there in 8.5--but only under the "asp" feature in IIS, which will only appear if you configured IIS to support classic ASP.

As for that "maximum concurrent connections" you show, that's an application pool characteristic, set in the "advanced settings" for a pool, in its "limits" section.

And as for the last set of applicationpool settings you show, those are from the aspnet.config file.

So you are discussing 3 very different sets of settings, and asking how two compare. They don't.

Finally, you happen to have asked a similar sort of question today in another ms forum thread (https://forums.iis.net/p/1247759/2156551.aspx), though I see this one here was opened over a year before.

I hope between this and that reply I may have helped you in connecting the dots. It sounds like you are trying to do some sort of tuning, in which case these all may be going deep in the weeds to get a resolution. Usually you can solve problems through other means, especially in getting diagnostics that really tell what a problem is, and then solving that problem. But let us know if this has been helpful.